# How to check for deleted versions in AWS SDK v3 S3 ListObjectVersionsCommand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The following code retrieves versions of a specific object in s3 (using `Prefix`).

```
const command = new ListObjectVersionsCommand({
  Bucket: s3Bucket,
  Prefix: fullPath
});

const response = await s3Client.send(command);
```

`response` has the following shape:

```
{
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": number,
        "requestId": string,
        "extendedRequestId": string,
        "cfId": string,
        "attempts": number,
        "totalRetryDelay": number
    },
    "DeleteMarkers": [
        {
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": string,
                "ID": string
            },
            "Key": string,
            "VersionId": string,
            "IsLatest": boolean,
            "LastModified": string
        }
    ],
    "IsTruncated": boolean,
    "KeyMarker": string,
    "MaxKeys": number,
    "Name": string,
    "Prefix": string,
    "VersionIdMarker": string,
    "Versions": [
        {
            "ETag": string,
            "Size": number,
            "StorageClass": string,
            "Key": string,
            "VersionId": string,
            "IsLatest": boolean,
            "LastModified": string,
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": string,
                "ID": string
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, how do I check which version has been deleted? I saw `response.DeleteMarkers` but it's pretty useless as it does not have any reference in or to `response.Versions`. I have been googling for a while now and even asked ChatGPT as well for help, but it just keeps on hallucinating answers and presenting them as facts, the answers I got from it are all wrong (https://chat.openai.com/share/5c1e8cfc-d8dd-45fa-a9e0-615ebf8119a6) and my search results hasn't presented me with an answer.

`response.DeleteMarkers.VersionId` and `response.Versions.VersionId` are different and not related to each other, seems like they are `Id`s of the individual entries.

When I look at it from the S3 Bucket, I can see that it seems like the `DeleteMarker` is supposed to have reference in each versions.

[image]

But the JSON response I get doesn't reflect this.

Example response:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '5ZWDEPHH55T26MBM',
    extendedRequestId: 'Ww6lV9BFYu5ZJ4ySVg0FVvGTolvwiQfLkmkXfUJnHRdzLBqx0xyNyNgvvYPfEYOBcSvgXHp3u3c=',
    cfId: 'yKku_yzmm53yfJJqeLCZBA7uRRzmuTxjkZo3nw7Oy7vDANvgGbP6Vg==',
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  DeleteMarkers: [
    {
      Owner: [Object],
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'EFEHxShryx7An1wB316DhGIgLqV1pv8m',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:01:17.000Z
    },
    {
      Owner: [Object],
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'MjuTh1iTW5mqTSjDX_kCtthHr0_crBUw',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:46:45.000Z
    },
    {
      Owner: [Object],
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'adY0h6KPkVlvpkUN_Qb7V4HT8ZFIdMsF',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:58:51.000Z
    },
    {
      Owner: [Object],
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'EXo0b3gRDiQoHKS7QcCT2ewIu4e9C0BK',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:40:04.000Z
    }
  ],
  IsTruncated: false,
  KeyMarker: '',
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  Name: 'dev-bourkehood-hub-test-bucket',
  Prefix: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
  VersionIdMarker: '',
  Versions: [
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: '70zachRrDvFuT7Vv1hm6lpQZoLtK78Vp',
      IsLatest: true,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:33:55.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'T6R5QDuElzyptmIDvdLSBwrFHd5Mvfv.',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:33:35.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'uHst7UpguHknpHRZEclsLi0LeFxZad4r',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:24:02.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'NE_zEN6oDC6mvpJVsrBnwJ.ZVzJbuRJ8',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:23:45.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'uwouMWFBqrLlT3cC_inY5w8UB0F07wzK',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:02:17.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'WVktjgHtAYPm60Csb_IuQWDGI305YJek',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:01:43.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'qT6vlzOqLTmq9tKtKSAbvfGdOz29BsJo',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T02:01:30.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'oHefQ6AnKcTUaxyCKMYzJszPb_8MGbYW',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:50:33.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'N3gvDTkIVa3C8JbPOyfMvvdGTSecZBsC',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:48:38.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'LPdfQ.gBc1f.jBixDYg.muRYRxnCHe1H',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:47:18.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"38b0d2ff1c03df82aea67222983d337e"',
      Size: 6,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: '_S1xv6r63Md6yOOZEX4pagUhWNwzsDWG',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:19:13.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'Ggy7wq8XnoZLsrtw.3Z1Rp7Q8I2Z_B7g',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T01:19:03.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"38b0d2ff1c03df82aea67222983d337e"',
      Size: 6,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'Y9RlaB9i0uq06.SWuQ5moXzB18YNvFNm',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:59:48.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'Sa4za24jIQVCZoSIqPTyRBMCMXlluWpw',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:59:27.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: '5MKHhqE9c.dXQNOX08Xe1HWAz9eFcocm',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:55:45.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"38b0d2ff1c03df82aea67222983d337e"',
      Size: 6,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: 'dCA6e.5VeDRpWvjxg4L1p3_SUaOEeuW5',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:23:10.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    },
    {
      ETag: '"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"',
      Size: 4,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
      Key: 'clients/647eddb692097dc08e54a33d/test.txt',
      VersionId: '3ZaLnwr63vNpeVrzjP14AGM5LuW9c0og',
      IsLatest: false,
      LastModified: 2023-06-16T00:06:21.000Z,
      Owner: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a specific Version of an object is deleted, it is **removed from Amazon S3**. It will not appear in any listing.

When an object is deleted in a version-enabled S3 bucket, a Delete Marker is added as the 'latest version'. This makes the object 'appear' as if it has been deleted, but previous versions have still been retained.

If the current version of an object is a Delete Marker, then the object will not appear in a normal listing of objects, but it will appear in `ListObjectVersions()`.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try this out and come back here!